# Swapping IDs & Python Performance

Tags: python, performance, swap, large-data

I'm hoping I can get help making my code run more efficiently. The purpose of my code is to take out the first ID (RUID) and replace it with a de-identified ID (RESPID) based on a key file of ids. The input data file is a large tab-delimited text file at about 2.5GB. The data is very wide, each row has thousands of columns. I have a function that works, but on the actual data it is incredibly slow. My first file has been running for 4 days and is only at 1.4GB. I don't know which part of my code is the most problematic, but I suspect it is where I build the row back together and write each row individually. Any advice on how to improve this would be greatly appreciated, 4 days is way too long for processing! Thank you!

```
def swap():
#input files
infile1 = open(r"Z:\ped_test.txt", 'rb')
keyfile = open(r"Z:\ruid_respid_test.txt", 'rb')

#output file
outfile=open(r"Z:\ped_testRESPID.txt", 'wb')
# create dictionary of RUID-RESPID 
COLUMN = 1 #Column containing RUID
RESPID={}
for k in keyfile:
    kList = k.rstrip('\r\n').split('\t')
    if kList[0] not in RESPID and kList[0] != "":
        RESPID[kList[0]]=kList[1]
#print RESPID
print "creating RESPID-RUID xwalk dictionary is done"

print "Start creating new file"
print str(datetime.datetime.now())
count=0
for line in infile1:
 #if not re.match('#', line): #if there is a header     
    sline = line.split()
    #slen = len(sline)
    RUID = sline[COLUMN]
    #print RUID
    C0 = sline[0]
    #print C0
    DAT=sline[2:]

    for key in RESPID:
        if key==RUID:
            NewID=RESPID[key]
    row=str(C0+'\t'+NewID)
    for a in DAT:
        row=row+'\t'+a
    #print row
outfile.write(row)
outfile.write('\n')

infile1.close()
keyfile.close()
outfile.close()

print "All Done: RESPID replacement is complete"
print str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several places you can speed things up. Primarily, its a problem with enumerating all of the keys in RESPID when you can just use the 'get' function to read the value. But since you have very wide lines, there are a couple of other tweeks that will make a difference.

```
def swap():
    #input files
    infile1 = open(r"Z:\ped_test.txt", 'rb')
    keyfile = open(r"Z:\ruid_respid_test.txt", 'rb')

    #output file
    outfile=open(r"Z:\ped_testRESPID.txt", 'wb')
    # create dictionary of RUID-RESPID 
    COLUMN = 1 #Column containing RUID
    RESPID={}
    for k in keyfile:
        kList = k.split('\t', 2)   # minor: jut grab what you need
        if kList[0] and kList[0] not in RESPID: # minor: do the cheap test first
            RESPID[kList[0]]=kList[1]
    #print RESPID
    print "creating RESPID-RUID xwalk dictionary is done"

    print "Start creating new file"
    print str(datetime.datetime.now())
    count=0
    for line in infile1:
     #if not re.match('#', line): #if there is a header     
        sline = line.split('\t', 2) # minor: just grab what you need
        #slen = len(sline)
        RUID = sline[COLUMN]
        #print RUID
        C0 = sline[0]
        #print C0
        DAT=sline[2:]

        # the biggie, just use a lookup
        #for key in RESPID:
        #   if key==RUID:
        #       NewID=RESPID[key]
        rows = '\t'.join([sline[0], RESPID.get(RUID, sline[1]), sline[2]])

        #row=str(C0+'\t'+NewID)
        #for a in DAT:
        #   row=row+'\t'+a
        #print row
    outfile.write(row)
    outfile.write('\n')

    infile1.close()
    keyfile.close()
    outfile.close()

    print "All Done: RESPID replacement is complete"
    print str(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: I had to add strip to RESPID.get(RUID, sline[1]) but otherwise this worked perfectly. 
final line was: 

row = '\t'.join([sline[0].strip(), RESPID.get(RUID, sline[1]).strip(), sline[2].strip()])

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate over RESPID.
Replace:

```
for key in RESPID:
    if key==RUID:
        NewID=RESPID[key]
```

with

```
NewId = RESPID[RUID]
```

It does the same thing because key is always RUID.
I am pretty sure that that will decrease the running time of the program dramatically because RESPID is huge and you are checking every key as many times as there are lines in "ped_test.txt".

Comment: thanks! that makes sense, now that I think about it!